# How to choose the best layouts for nested JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I plan to design a gui program which contains the one outer JPanel which contains a lot of recurring JPanel which has text and button.Yet , I couldn't decide which layouts are suitable for this task.I want it to be like this :

[image]

I just copied and pasted first JPanel which will be recurred programmatically like you see in the image.
Which layouts should I use in order to get a result like this ?

Comment: Looks like the outer panel should use a vertical `BoxLayout` and the inner one could use a horizontal `BoxLayout` or `GridLayout`. Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). To get a definite answer, you would need to specify resizing behavior.

Comment: @user1803551 thank you for link , but what do you mean by "specify resizing behaviour"

Comment: When you resize the frame, how do you want the space to be distributed between components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my head it looks like this:

`JScrollPane` > `JPanel (outerPane)` > `JPanel (innerPane [many])`

Based on this, we need to think which layout manager is the `outerPane` going to use and the `innerPane`s...

In order to provide spacing between `innerPane`s I would go for [`GridLayout (rows, columns, hgap, vgap)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-int-int-) like:

```
GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5);
```

Now for each `innerPane` we could go for `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout` or `FlowLayout`, let's see what would happen with each:

- If we used `FlowLayout` the components wouldn't be in a "grid" or "table" like layout, so, it's a no no... this is how it would look like:

  [image]

  Altough they seem like what we need, I'm not sure if each label is going to change over time or not, but you could try...

  - Using `GridLayout` would make our `JButton`s to take the whole space of the cell, and it wouldn't look good (at least when resizing it), here's an image with the before and after resizing the GUI to show what I mean (cropped to not use a lot of space in the post):

  [image]

  If your GUI won't resize you can go with this path, if it will, then you should another layout.

  - `GridBagLayout` is my favorite in this case because each label will stay in their own column and the buttons won't fill all the available space and our GUI will look more like the image you posted:

  [image]

  In the example above, I used a `CustomBorder` class to provide spacing between the `innerPane`s and the `outerPane` while also providing a a colored border as well as showing the vertical `JScrollPane` always.

  The code that produces those outputs is:

  ```
  package sof;

  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import java.awt.Insets;
  import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

  import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
  import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

  public class NestedPanels {
      private JFrame frame;
      private JPanel outerPane;
      private JPanel innerPane;
      private GridBagConstraints gbc;
      private JScrollPane scrollPane;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new NestedPanels()::createAndShowGui);
      }

      private void createAndShowGui() {
          frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

          outerPane = new JPanel();
          outerPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));

          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              innerPane = new JPanel();
              innerPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

              gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

              gbc.gridx = 0;
              gbc.gridy = 0;
              gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
              gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

              innerPane.add(new JLabel("Recurring JLabel1"), gbc);

              gbc.gridx++;
              innerPane.add(new JLabel("Recurring JLabel2"), gbc);
              gbc.gridx++;
              innerPane.add(new JLabel("Recurring JLabel3"), gbc);
              gbc.gridx++;
              innerPane.add(new JButton("Recurring JButton1"), gbc);

              innerPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

              outerPane.add(innerPane);
          }
          outerPane.setBorder(new CustomBorder(5, Color.BLACK));

          scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outerPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

          frame.add(scrollPane);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("serial")
      class CustomBorder extends AbstractBorder {
          private int gap;
          private Color color;
          public CustomBorder(int gap, Color color) {
              this.gap = gap;
              this.color = color;
          }

          @Override
          public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
              return new Insets(gap, gap, gap, gap);
          }

          @Override
          public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
              super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
              Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
              g2d.setColor(color);
              g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - 1, height - 1));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Play with the border styles to get the desired one, I painted the border with a -1 pixel on the GUI, if I didn't it would only show left and top borders...

- Another option would be using a `JTable` but I leave that to you